# File Renaming using the Correct extension in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following code that i would like when a user uploads a file it ensures file renaming extension uses the correct file name extension

```
function ifImageExistsSave(Request $request, String $file_name, String $directory)
   {
       {           
           $target_dir = "images/"; 
           $current_time = Carbon::now();
           $image_name = $current_time . substr(str_shuffle(MD5(microtime())), 0, 10) . '.jpeg';
           $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES[$file_name]["name"]);

           if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_name]["tmp_name"],$target_file))
           {
               return $target_file;
           } 
            else {
                return "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                }
       }
```

Comment: what you mean with "the correct extension"?

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem. Pls edit your answer to clarify what your problem is and what is the behaviour you aspect

Comment: Edited it sorry it was supposed to file renaming hope you understand right now?